# hibernate spring session rolls back updates after some period of time

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I run my tomcat app - spring3+hibernate3(mysql).
Hibernate creates the session. I have no problem with inserts.
But after that I am trying to make an update in sql IDE (e.g. sql developer)

**update t_user set password='123' where id=1;**

row updates but (!) my updates ***rolled back*** after some time. 
I think it happens when session flushes. Please fix me if I am wrong.

Also I am trying to execute that update with different variations via java code.

For instance:

```
@Override
public void addUser(User u) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(u);
}

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(u);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(u);
```

So the only chance to make some updates in my database is to stop my application and execute the query.

I think that session could configured wrongly:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="120"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Also i tried flush the session:

```
sesion.flush();
```

I have a such property in hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
 <property name="hibernate.flushMode">ALWAYS</property>
```

Or maybe problem with mysql...
Does anybody encountered that problem?
Please advice.

**UPDATE:**
I am using transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>        
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode">ALWAYS</property>       

        <mapping class="com.dao.model.user.User"/>        

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: in your Spring configuration, are you using a transaction manager?

Comment: use commit on the transaction to save the value. Dont know how you are managing the transactions from the code you have given, please paste code.

Comment: @Dan Matthews-Grout, I have updated the post. I am using transaction manager.

Comment: @Zeus I am using transaction manager. Please see the update.

Comment: Add your hibernate.cfg.xml. Only adding a `HibernateTransactionManager` isn't going to do much, you must also have a proper transaction setup. Also you state that your update is rolled back, but have you actually committed that update statement!

Comment: @M. Deinum, I am using Transaction annotation. for example all insert statements work fine. I don't think there is a big difference between insert and update because both statements executed from one source. I mean same transactionManager. added hibernate.cfg.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the actual transaction demarcation so that Spring can create the transactional context that the `SessionFactory` should use.

### Regular use case

You could, for instance, annotate your transactional method with `@Transactional` and trigger its processing with `<tx:annotation-driven/>` as you are already using the XML configuration (`@EnableTransactionManagement` if you are using java config).

You shouldn't call `flush` yourself as the infrastructure will do that automatically when it needs to by default.

Check the [transaction management section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) of the documentation for more information.

### Open session in view

You may just as well have all this in combination with `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. In that case, the same principle applies: having the session open for your request is not enough, check this note from [the javadoc of OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html):

> NOTE: This filter will by default not flush the Hibernate Session, with the flush mode set to FlushMode.NEVER. It assumes to be used in combination with service layer transactions that care for the flushing: The active transaction manager will temporarily change the flush mode to FlushMode.AUTO during a read-write transaction, with the flush mode reset to FlushMode.NEVER at the end of each transaction. If you intend to use this filter without transactions, consider changing the default flush mode (through the "flushMode" property).

So you need to flag your method to be transactional so that Spring's transaction abstraction can take over and flush when it needs to. Adding `@Transactional` for your transactional method and enabling its processing through `<tx:annotation-driven/>` are probably the only things that you need to do. Please read the documentation first to understand when you need to add this annotation.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but I have <tx:annotation-driven/> in my applicationContext.xml. also I have a hibernate filter in my web.xml - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInWievFilter

Comment: I am going to try session.refresh(entity) after update. need some time to check it

Comment: I have updated my answer with that useful information. Please check "open session in view"

Comment: thnx for explanation @snicoll. so why my sql-update from sql developer resets (roll backs) to previous value?

Comment: it is really hard to say without seeing the code in action. But that shouldn't be the case if you create a proper transactional context for your method as I explained.